# find and replace characters in a particular column in a table using python

Tags: python, replace, find

I have a 67 different tables (with hundreds of thousands of rows) with multiple columns. One column is named PARCEL_ID. The PARCEL_ID field has characters like "-" or space or "/", etc. I would like to remove all these "-", or empty space, or "/", etc characters from the PARCEL_ID field from all the tables in a folder.  The tables are dbf files. I want to get the PARCEL_ID column values like "04-2N-07-00 00-0001-0000" to this "042N07000000010000". Basically get rid of empty spaces and dashes and any other character that i dont want in there. How do I do that using python? This is what I am trying unsuccesfully:

```
import arcpy
import re
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Workspace\PARCELS_2012\Nal_dbf_test'

fcs = arcpy.ListTables()

s = ['PARCEL_ID']

for fc in fcs:
    print "** Now working on "+fc
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
    for field in fields:
        if field.baseName in s:
            PARCEL_ID = re.sub(r'[-/ ]', '', PARCEL_ID)
            print "   Parcelno cleaned"
            if not field.baseName in s:
                print "   Already clean"
print fc + " is cleaned."
```

Comment: You need to add more context. Is your table in a text file? Show the first lines of your table. Show some sample output you would like to create. Also, show the source code of your attempts you have done so far to solve this.

Comment: In a database or a csv or a string or... what?

Comment: sorry guys, very new in python and in this group. The table is a dbf file. It has multiple columns. I want to get the PARCEL_ID column values like "04-2N-07-00   00-0001-0000" to this "042N07000000010000". Basically get rid of empty spaces and dashes and any other character that i dont want in there.

Comment: Add all the new info as an edit to your question. That info gets kkind of lost if you add it as a comment.

Comment: What are the attributes of `field`?  Is there one that contains the string you want to edit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
PARCEL_ID = re.sub(r'[-/ ]', '', PARCEL_ID)
```

Add any other characters you don't want between the brackets.

Comment: ok. how can I get this repeat for 67 tables in a folder? I am trying to clean up the PARCEL_ID field for all the parcels in 67 different Florida counties. P.S. I am just starting python (or any programming for that matter) and I truly apologize for my ignorance. But I really want to learn even how to ask a question and appreciate your patience and guidance.

Comment: You will have to explain how you are reading in and then storing your tables for me to answer that.

Comment: import arcpy
import re
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Workspace\PARCELIDCLEANUP.gdb'
fcs = arcpy.ListTables()

s = ['PARCEL_ID']
for fc in fcs:
    print "** Now working on "+fc
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
    for field in fields:
        if field.baseName in s:
            PARCEL_ID = re.sub(r'[-/ ]', '', PARCEL_ID)
            print "   Parcelno cleaned"
            if not field.baseName in s:
                print "   Already clean"

Comment: I think that it would be best if you included this as an edit in your original post (as Mike Muller requested).  One cannot understand python in a single line like this.

Comment: Wnen I wrote `PARCEL_ID` as the variable, you didn't have to take me literally.  Replace that with the appropriate variable in your code.

Comment: I was trying to delete the unwanted characters only from the PARCEL_ID column. I was trying to avoid removing the listed characters from other columns in the table.

Comment: I understand that, but `PARCEL_ID` is not a variable in your code, so you can't replace anything within it.  See my newest comment in the original post.